# Delete .mp3 file if .m4a file with same name exists in directory

Tags: bash, mp3, m4a

I ended up with many of my songs in both .m4a and .mp3 format. The duplicate .mp3s are in the same folders as their corresponding .m4as, and I'd like to delete the .mp3s. I'm trying to write a bash script to do that for me, but I'm very new to bash scripting and unsure of what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ~/music/artist/album/* ; do
    if [ -f f.m4a ] && [ -f f.mp3 ] ; then
        rm f.mp3
        echo "dup deleted"
    fi
done
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could figure out what's going wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: `f.m4a` -> `"$f.m4a"`

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
# No need to loop through unrelated files (*.txt, directories, etc), right?
for f in ~/music/artist/album/*.m4a; do
    f="${f%.*}"
    if [[ -f ${f}.mp3 ]]; then
        rm -f "${f}.mp3" && echo >&2 "${f}.mp3 deleted"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Well, I thought it was working, but it's not. The .mp3 file still is not being deleted.

Comment: @JesseEvers I did test it, it worked for me. I’m afraid, I can’t say anything else so long as you did not provide any details.

Comment: There don't seem to be any more details to provide as far as I can tell. I don't get any output when I run the program, and the mp3 file in the folder is not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ~/music/artist/album/* ; do
    f="${f%.*}" # remove extension in simple cases (not tar.gz)
    if [[ -f ${f}.m4a && -f ${f}.mp3 ]] ; then
        rm -f "${f}.mp3" && echo "dup deleted"
    fi
done
```